# Tkinter image as frame style

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I'm using the code I found here: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Demo/tkinter/ttk/roundframe.py which gives me frames with rounded corners. (Here's a link to the [related article](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ttk+Frame+with+Custom+Borders) by Bryan Oakley). However, I'd like to colour the background of the frames produced using that style.

```
"""Ttk Frame with rounded corners.

Based on an example by Bryan Oakley, found at: http://wiki.tcl.tk/20152"""
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

img1 = tkinter.PhotoImage("frameFocusBorder", data="""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""")

img2 = tkinter.PhotoImage("frameBorder", data="""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""")

style = ttk.Style()

style.element_create("RoundedFrame", "image", "frameBorder",
    ("focus", "frameFocusBorder"), border=16, sticky="nsew")

style.layout("RoundedFrame", [("RoundedFrame", {"sticky": "nsew"})])
style.configure("TEntry", borderwidth=0)

frame = ttk.Frame(style="RoundedFrame", padding=10)
frame.pack(fill='x')

frame2 = ttk.Frame(style="RoundedFrame", padding=10)
frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

entry = ttk.Entry(frame, text='Test')
entry.pack(fill='x')
entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda evt: frame.state(["focus"]))
entry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda evt: frame.state(["!focus"]))

text = tkinter.Text(frame2, borderwidth=0, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
text.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
text.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda evt: frame2.state(["focus"]))
text.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda evt: frame2.state(["!focus"]))

root.mainloop()
```

It *looks* to me like what that file does is that it applies an image as a style sheet, and that image is the enormous text block. Consequently, when I try giving either the style itself or the frames background colours, Python returns me: `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"`.

I *think* the solution would be to change the image. After some research, I find that apparently the PhotoImage class takes 'base64-encoded GIF files' as strings, now, how do I decode this, alternatively, what image format would I feed PhotoImage so that I can change the frame appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [base64.decodestring](http://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.decodestring) to decode the encoded image.

```
import base64

with open('frameBorder.gif', 'wb') as f:
    decoded = base64.decodestring(b"""
    R0lGODlhQABAAPcAAHx+fMTCxKSipOTi5JSSlNTS1LSytPTy9IyKjMzKzKyq
    rOzq7JyanNza3Ly6vPz6/ISChMTGxKSmpOTm5JSWlNTW1LS2tPT29IyOjMzO
    zKyurOzu7JyenNze3Ly+vPz+/OkAKOUA5IEAEnwAAACuQACUAAFBAAB+AFYd
    QAC0AABBAAB+AIjMAuEEABINAAAAAHMgAQAAAAAAAAAAAKjSxOIEJBIIpQAA
    sRgBMO4AAJAAAHwCAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP+eEP8CZ/8Aif8AAG0BDAUAAJEA
    AHwAAIXYAOfxAIESAHwAAABAMQAbMBZGMAAAIEggJQMAIAAAAAAAfqgaXESI
    5BdBEgB+AGgALGEAABYAAAAAAACsNwAEAAAMLwAAAH61MQBIAABCM8B+AAAU
    AAAAAAAApQAAsf8Brv8AlP8AQf8Afv8AzP8A1P8AQf8AfgAArAAABAAADAAA
    AACQDADjAAASAAAAAACAAADVABZBAAB+ALjMwOIEhxINUAAAANIgAOYAAIEA
    AHwAAGjSAGEEABYIAAAAAEoBB+MAAIEAAHwCACABAJsAAFAAAAAAAGjJAGGL
    AAFBFgB+AGmIAAAQAABHAAB+APQoAOE/ABIAAAAAAADQAADjAAASAAAAAPiF
    APcrABKDAAB8ABgAGO4AAJAAqXwAAHAAAAUAAJEAAHwAAP8AAP8AAP8AAP8A
    AG0pIwW3AJGSAHx8AEocI/QAAICpAHwAAAA0SABk6xaDEgB8AAD//wD//wD/
    /wD//2gAAGEAABYAAAAAAAC0/AHj5AASEgAAAAA01gBkWACDTAB8AFf43PT3
    5IASEnwAAOAYd+PuMBKQTwB8AGgAEGG35RaSEgB8AOj/NOL/ZBL/gwD/fMkc
    q4sA5UGpEn4AAIg02xBk/0eD/358fx/4iADk5QASEgAAAALnHABkAACDqQB8
    AMyINARkZA2DgwB8fBABHL0AAEUAqQAAAIAxKOMAPxIwAAAAAIScAOPxABIS
    AAAAAIIAnQwA/0IAR3cAACwAAAAAQABAAAAI/wA/CBxIsKDBgwgTKlzIsKFD
    gxceNnxAsaLFixgzUrzAsWPFCw8kDgy5EeQDkBxPolypsmXKlx1hXnS48UEH
    CwooMCDAgIJOCjx99gz6k+jQnkWR9lRgYYDJkAk/DlAgIMICkVgHLoggQIPT
    ighVJqBQIKvZghkoZDgA8uDJAwk4bDhLd+ABBmvbjnzbgMKBuoA/bKDQgC1F
    gW8XKMgQOHABBQsMI76wIIOExo0FZIhM8sKGCQYCYA4cwcCEDSYPLOgg4Oro
    uhMEdOB84cCAChReB2ZQYcGGkxsGFGCgGzCFCh1QH5jQIW3xugwSzD4QvIIH
    4s/PUgiQYcCG4BkC5P/ObpaBhwreq18nb3Z79+8Dwo9nL9I8evjWsdOX6D59
    fPH71Xeef/kFyB93/sln4EP2Ebjegg31B5+CEDLUIH4PVqiQhOABqKFCF6qn
    34cHcfjffCQaFOJtGaZYkIkUuljQigXK+CKCE3po40A0trgjjDru+EGPI/6I
    Y4co7kikkAMBmaSNSzL5gZNSDjkghkXaaGIBHjwpY4gThJeljFt2WSWYMQpZ
    5pguUnClehS4tuMEDARQgH8FBMBBBExGwIGdAxywXAUBKHCZkAIoEEAFp33W
    QGl47ZgBAwZEwKigE1SQgAUCUDCXiwtQIIAFCTQwgaCrZeCABAzIleIGHDD/
    oIAHGUznmXABGMABT4xpmBYBHGgAKGq1ZbppThgAG8EEAW61KwYMSOBAApdy
    pNp/BkhAAQLcEqCTt+ACJW645I5rLrgEeOsTBtwiQIEElRZg61sTNBBethSw
    CwEA/Pbr778ABywwABBAgAAG7xpAq6mGUUTdAPZ6YIACsRKAAbvtZqzxxhxn
    jDG3ybbKFHf36ZVYpuE5oIGhHMTqcqswvyxzzDS/HDMHEiiggQMLDxCZXh8k
    BnEBCQTggAUGGKCB0ktr0PTTTEfttNRQT22ABR4EkEABDXgnGUEn31ZABglE
    EEAAWaeN9tpqt832221HEEECW6M3wc+Hga3SBgtMODBABw00UEEBgxdO+OGG
    J4744oZzXUEDHQxwN7F5G7QRdXxPoPkAnHfu+eeghw665n1vIKhJBQUEADs=""")
    f.write(decoded)
```

Change the decoded file `frameBorder.gif`, and encode it back using following code.

(Following code output base64-encoded string)

```
import base64

with open('frameBorder.gif', 'rb') as f:
    encoded = base64.encodestring(f.read())
    print(encoded.decode('latin1'))
```

Comment: ... Huh. Simpler than I expected, didn't expect that there was a python function to do that. I suppose the reverse would be 'encode'?

Comment: Your code contain `encoded` version. My first code `decode` it. The second code `encode` it back.